# Tomcat fails to return syn requests to F5

Tags: tomcat, tcp

I have an F5 LTM sitting in front of two tomcat servers which host 4 applications. When I initially create the pools and add the members to the LTM I can hit all applications. This is the weird part, after an undetermined amount of time the tomcat servers stop responding to SYN requests sent by the F5. Makes me think it is some type of time out issue. I can still hit the tomcat servers directly and can curl pages on the tomcat servers via the CLI of the F5. Pool members are healthy.

Here is a TCP dump from the F5 when I attempt to access one of the tomcat applications via its VIP.

2014-01-17 15:38:50.500324 20.980713 0 177 10.192.209.1 10.192.209.11 TCP 8081 65281 209 177 OUT s1/tmm3 : 65281 > 8081 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=4380 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 TSval=2716693891 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

I have disabled tcp_timestamps and tcp_window_scaling on the tomcat host. Any ideas? I have been working on this for about a week and have hit a wall.

Comment: This was related to a network routing issue and has been resolved.